# Open tab on click on link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a tab when the user clicks on an image link on the following website: 
http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/index.php/jadever-jad-jce-counting-scale.html

The code of the tabs is the following:

```
<ul class="tabs clearer">
  <li id="tab-additional"><a href="#" class="current">Product 
Specifications</a></li>                                                         
  <li id="tab-description"><a href="#">Product Features</a></li>
  <li id="tab-downloads"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
  <li id="tab-feefo_reviews"><a href="#">Feefo Reviews</a></li>                                                                                                     
</ul>
```

The ID of the tab is "tab-feefo_reviews". The user clicks on the Feefo logo under the product name.

and this is my code:

```
 <a onclick="javascript:window.location.href='#tab-feefo_reviews'";><img 
 src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>" /></a>
```

On clicking, it jumps to the tab section, but does not open the tab. Is there a way of achieving this with inline javascript?

Comment: We would have absolutely no idea considering that you haven't mentioned what sort of tabs you're using.

Comment: Please add your tab html structure also?

Comment: sorry just added the structure

Comment: Still unclear. What kind of tab plugin are you using? You need to programatically make the tab load whatever URL fragment you intend to load. Just setting the window location does not change anything.

Comment: Yes like what @Terry said. Maybe just want to show the tab review by not opening a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `jQuery('#tab-feefo_reviews a').click()` to your onclick event (the page already uses jquery, this is the quickest inline code).

Also, the anchor should include a href="javascript:void(0);" or even better, the hash of the anchor. And the onclick event doesn't need the "javascript:" prefix.

So change the anchor to this:

`<a href="#tab-feefo_reviews" onclick="jQuery('#tab-feefo_reviews a').click()" >`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this without knowledge of future changes to the site.

EDIT: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

---

First, set all the tabs to an empty class name, and .

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll("ul.tabs a");
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].className = "";
}
var panels = document.querySelectorAll("div.tabs-panels > div.panel");
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
        panels[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Then, set the *current* tab to #tab-feefo_reviews and display the right panel.

```
var tab = document.getElementById("tab-feefo_reviews");
tab.className = "current";
var panel = document.getElementById("acctab-feefo_reviews");
panel.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried yet but I guess this should work using jquery.

```
  <a href="#" id="openSesame"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>" /></a>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
   $('#openSesame').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.clearer').find('#tab-feefo_reviews a').addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to navigate within page (use `href="#id"`) and activate accordion panel

```
<a href="#tab-feefo_reviews" onclick="javascript:jQuery('#tab-feefo_reviews>a').click();">
  <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc(); ?>" />
</a>
```